# Sage CRM - It is possible to create an appointment through Classic ASP code?

Tags: sage-crm

Using this:

```
var NewComm = CRM.CreateRecord("Communication");
NewComm("Comm_ChannelId") = Request.Form("chanId");
NewComm("Comm_Type") = "Appointment";
NewComm("Comm_DateTime") = Request.Form("initialHour");
NewComm.SaveChanges()
```

I can see in the DDBB that the Communication is created

Just for testing (and to see if it needs a Comm_Link row to be able to show), i updated some row in the Comm_Link table (CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId column) to the ID equals to the Communication i just created, but still i do not see my Comm when clicking in My Calender

There is somethgin else i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain fields that are required for security, namely Team (Channel) fields and Territory (Secterr) fields.

With Communications, you also need to make sure there are other default fields, as Communicationa are often filtered.

For example, Communication lists are filtered by the Status field = Pending by default, so make sure the comm_status field is set.

Also, all Communications generally have an Action (comm_action) and some other fields.

We advise setting the following fields, in addition to those you have already set:

```
NewComm("comm_status") = 'Pending';
NewComm("comm_action") = 'Meeting';
NewComm("comm_secterr") = *A Territory Id*;
NewComm("comm_subject") = 'A Subject';
NewComm("Comm_ToDateTime") = *End Date/Time*;

NewCommLink("cmli_comm_userid") = *The User Id*;
NewCommLink("cmli_comm_communicationid") = *The Communication Id*;
NewCommLink("cmli_comm_personid") = *The Person Id if required*;
NewCommLink("cmli_comm_companyid") = *The Company Id if required*;
```

Hope that helps!

Six Ticks Support

Comment: With the NewComm object, there is method to retrieve the Id of the recently created record?

Comment: Or even better, there is a object to create an Appointment directly? By Passing some values?

Comment: Yeah, you can get the Id. I think that's probably better as a separate question though, to help other SO users who are looking for the same thing. Create a new question about how to get the Id and we'll answer that :)

Comment: Done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490658/sage-crm-there-is-method-to-retrieve-the-id-on-the-recently-created-record-whe Let me test some things and will accept this answer

Comment: Also, i think it needs to fill the `Comm_ToDateTime` column. Once i created the Comm and Comm_link in ASP the Communication still does not appear at My Calendar. Then i put some value in the  `Comm_ToDateTime` and then appeared